# Add field to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want to add a field to JSON. I do have a working solution, but it's ugly (using eval). Is there a nicer way to add a field?

```
var json = {};
var id = "test";
eval("json." + id + " = 5;");
console.log(json.test);
```

UPDATE: Sorry, my question was somewhat unclear.
I want to use the variable id, which has the value of the new field.

Cheers,
Bernhard

Comment: `json[id] = 5`. Also, that's a JavaScript object, not JSON, don't get them mixed up! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation

Comment: That's not JSON, that's a javascript object. You seem to want to add a property with a certain value. No offense, but searching online should easily yield useful results. Are we missing some info?

Comment: please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Comment: obj.id = 5, JSON.stringify(obj)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use like below instead:

Use like this:

```
json[id] = 5;
```

Thus, in your case:

```
var json = {};
var id = "test";
json[id] = 5;
console.log(json.test); //will print 5
// OR
console.log(json['test']); //will print 5
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add like this :

```
var json = {};
json.test = 5;
console.log(json.test);
```

or

```
var json = {};
json["test"] = 5;
console.log(json.test);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var json = {};
var id = "test";
eval("json." + id + " = 5;");
console.log(json.test);
```

and this

```
var json2 = {};
json2.test = 5;
console.log(json2.test);
```

or this

```
var json3 = {};
json3["test"] = 5;
console.log(json3.test);
```

First example is undesirable.

Comment: The first example should not exist.

Comment: Yes. First one is undesirable.